# C# MongoDB Query with BsonClassMaps

Tags: c#, mongodb, domain-driven-design, mapping

I'm new to MongoDB and was wondering about querying for domain objects with registered BsonClassMaps.
Consider the following Mappings:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<VoyageNumber>(cm =>
            { cm.MapField<string>(p => p.Id); });

BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Schedule>(cm =>
        { cm.MapField<DateTime>(p => p.EndDate); cm.MapField<DateTime>(p => p.StartDate); });

BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Voyage>(cm =>
            { cm.MapIdField<VoyageNumber>(p => p.VoyageNumber); cm.MapField<Schedule>(p => p.Schedule); });
```

The domain entity is "Voyage". In this simple example it consists of a complex type "Schedule" (with start date and end date) and a VoyageNumber (with a string id field).
"VoyageNumber" is the identifier for the entity.

Now I can insert a new voyage just fine with:

```
MongoCollection<Voyage> mongoVoyages = context.MyDB.GetCollection<Voyage>("Voyages");

mongoVoyages.Insert<Voyage>(voyage);
```

I can retrieve one Voyage via:

```
MongoCollection mongoVoyages = context.MyDB.GetCollection("Voyages");

BsonDocument result = mongoVoyages.FindOneAs<BsonDocument>();
BsonDocument sched = result["Schedule"].AsBsonDocument;
DateTime start = sched["StartDate"].AsDateTime;
//etc...
```

Now of course I'd like to search a voyage by Id. How can I achieve this with the mappings shown above? I tried something like this and failed:

```
Query.EQ("VoyageNumber", someStringID)
```

I'm using the official C# driver 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With above classes registration you will have document like this in mongodb:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "_id": someStringID
  },
  "Schedule": {
    "EndDate": "Sun, 10 Apr 2011 13:06:25 GMT +03:00",
    "StartDate": "Sun, 10 Apr 2011 13:06:25 GMT +03:00"
  }
}
```

So if you want get `Voyage` by `VoyageNumber` Id you should use following query:

```
Query.EQ("_id._id", someStringID)
```

**Note:** You no need `BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap` for class if you map all fileds because it will be serialized by default without any registration. Also you can do custom serialization using attributes like `[BsonId]`, `[BsonIgnore]`. For more details check [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial) or ask another question ;).

From documentation:

> You can either create this class map
>   yourself or simply allow the class map
>   to be created automatically when first
>   needed (called "automapping"). You can
>   exert some control over the
>   automapping process either by
>   decorating your classes with
>   serialization related attributes or by
>   using initialization code (attributes
>   are very convenient to use but for
>   those who prefer to keep serialization
>   details out of their domain classes be
>   assured that anything that can be done
>   with attributes can also be done
>   without them)

Comment: Thank you, that works and it furthered my understanding of document oriented DBs. So you say that I dont need to map any other fields except the IdField?

Comment: @Malkier: No, you no need to map at all. At least in your example. I've added some notes from documentation to my question.